# List of paired Bluetooth devices in iOS without scanning again and again

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am not using the MFI Program and developing an application for a custom made wearable.
The requirement is such that If once a paired device will be shown as a separate list item after pressing the scan button. 
Also this process should not require scanning again i.e the list of paired devices should be retrieved on app load only.

Moreover on scanning again these devices should not appear in the scanned devices list.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. Your app can store the details of peripherals that you want to connect to and it is up to you how you display the data

Comment: Yes. That is I want to know that as soon as I am opening my app I should have the info of the previously paired devices and on pressing the scan button it should not scan for the previously connected devices. I have tried retrievePeripherals method but I am not able to get any devices without the scan process being initiated. If possible, please provide some code to get the list of paired devices. Thanks for responding to the query.

Comment: You don't typically pair with BLE devices (only if you are using encryption).  You need to initiate a scan for the device offering the service if `retrievePeripherals` doesn't return it.

Comment: yes that is the paradox I am facing. I do not want to scan to retrieve the previously connected devices and without scanning -retrievePeripherals is not returning anything. So, If any other approach is available to get the list of previously paired devices then do let me know as it can be easily done in Android. Thanks Paul

Comment: Why don't you want to scan?  It is how CoreBluetooth works.  Simply scan and when you match the device identifier, initiate a connection.  It takes a few seconds at most.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the inputs. I will follow the scanning approach then. Also are you available on facebook? I would like to take your recommendations while I am working on this project. it will be a great help if we can have a direct contact.